# How to translate, "Allow users to enter a time or time range." in Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

I'm debating if this:

> Permite aos usuários inserir tempo ou intervalo de tempo

or:

> Permite usuários inserirem um horário ou intervalo de tempo

Any advice?

Comment: Is it a time like 9.30, 12 noon, etc.? As in: windows needs to install updates and restart your computer; enter a time or time range that is suitable for you?

Comment: Exactly that type of idea. a time or time range for something to be done, something to happen, in the above scenario you are creating a form and trying to specify a time or a time range that users can select on the form based on their availability.

Comment: Not sure that time range works in English: Enter the ***time or time slots***.

Comment: TIme range is not right in English.

Comment: Permite aos usuários colocar a hora ou faixa horária.

Answer (score 2):

[Permitir](http://www.aulete.com.br/permitir), with this meaning, is a ditransitive verb (*permitir algo a alguém*). The direct object is the thing or action to be allowed, and the indirect object is the individual to get the permission.

The noun clause verb ("inserir") has an impersonal subject and, as such, does not agree with the direct object number ("usuários").

If "time" points to a specific time on the clock, it's better conveyed as "horário".

Adding it all up:

> Permitir aos usuários inserir um horário ou intervalo de tempo.

---

[Permitir](http://www.aulete.com.br/permitir), com este significado, é um verbo transitivo direto e indireto (*permitir algo a alguém*). O objeto direto é a coisa ou ação a ser permitida, e o objeto indireto é o indivíduo a receber a permissão.

O verbo da oração subordinada substantiva ("inserir") não concorda com o número do objeto direto ("aos usuários"), porque o sujeito dele é impessoal.

Se "time" representa um horário específico, fica melhor traduzido como "horário" mesmo.

Combinando tudo:

> Permitir aos usuários inserir um horário ou intervalo de tempo.

Answer (score 1):

The word you need is *hora*:

> Permite aos usuários inserir uma hora ou intervalo de tempo.

One meaning of [*hora* (Michaelis 4,5)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=hora) is ‘exact time or moment’, as in *o jogo começou à hora prevista*. In questions we tend to use the plural―as in *a que horas começa o jogo?*―but the meaning is the same. [*Horário* (Michaelis)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=hor%C3%A1rio) means ‘timetable’.

Here’s an [example form GitHub (2016)](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs.pt-br/blob/master/articles/hdinsight/hdinsight-storm-correlation-topology.md) where *hora* and *intervalo de tempo* are used in the sense you mean (emphasis mine):

> Quando solicitado, selecione s para pesquisar pelo evento INICIAR. Você será solicitado a **inserir uma hora** de início e encerramento para definir um **intervalo de tempo**; apenas os **eventos entre essas duas horas** serão retornados.
>
> Use o seguinte formato ao **inserir as horas** de início e encerramento: HH:MM e “am” ou “pm”. Por exemplo, 11:20pm.

You can also say *faixa* instead of *intervalo*. And in fact, because [*horário* (Michaelis)](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=hor%C3%A1rio) is also an adjective related to *hora*, you could say *intervalo horário* instead of *intervalo de tempo*. Both are fine. *Intervalo de tempo* is probably more common, but *intervalo horário* looks good in your example, coming right after *hora*:

> Permite aos usuários inserir uma hora ou intervalo horário.
>
> Permite aos usuários inserir uma hora ou faixa horária.

Comment: Acho que sim, so que intervalo de tempo pode de faixa de tempo, e não intervalo.

Comment: @Lambie Não compreendi bem, "pode de faixa": queres dizer que se pode dizer *faixa de tempo* ou *intervalo de tempo*?

Comment: pode ser: faixa horária. :) Não gosto muito desse inserir. Se coloca, se digita, até se entra (dados). Se insere uma palavra em um texto.

Comment: @Lambie Calculei que fosse isso. Não conhecia esse uso de *faixa*.

Comment: esse time range tá errado em inglês. São time slots, e não time ranges. Por exemplo, para aviões, se fala em faixa horária. É a  mesma ideia aqui.

Comment: @Lambie Felizmente só tenho que me pronunciar sobre as expressões em português :) Incorporei a tua sugestão; obrigado.

Comment: Tudo bem. Faixa horária é bem conhecido tanto aí que no Brasil. Você fala francês---bem, por acaso?

Comment: @Lambie Leio bem francês, mas falo mal. Porquê?

Comment: @Porque muitos anos atrás eu conhecia um Jacinto em Paris. E a sua personalidade - até em linha - parece com a dele. :)

Comment: @Lambie Foi com certeza outro Jacinto. Passei ao todo uns dez dias em Paris.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52831/discussion-between-lambie-and-jacinto).